# Postgres - order by aggregate function on SUM

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

I use **Postgres** sql function it in my sql query like:

```
SELECT
        message.id,
        note,
        earned_media_direct(
            SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered)::int,
            CAST(SUM(message_stat.clicks) AS bigint),
            team.earned_media_multi_clicks::int,
            SUM(message_stat.likes)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_likes::int,
            SUM(message_stat.comments)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_comments::int,
            SUM(message_stat.shares)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_shares::int
        ) AS media_points,
        count(*) OVER() AS total_count
    FROM message
    LEFT JOIN team ON team.id = 10
    WHERE team_id = 10
    GROUP BY message.id, team.id
    {$orderBy}
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 1
```

When returning a list of messages I want to use `ORDER BY rank` (Sorting by "rank" really means sorting by Media Points)

The function `earned_media_direct` is defined within Postgres like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.earned_media_direct(posts bigint, clicks bigint, clicks_multiplier numeric, likes bigint, likes_multiplier numeric, comments bigint, comments_multiplier numeric, reshares bigint, shares_multiplier numeric)
RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$

BEGIN
    RETURN COALESCE(clicks, 0) * clicks_multiplier + 
        COALESCE(likes, 0) * likes_multiplier + 
        COALESCE(comments, 0) * comments_multiplier + 
        (COALESCE(posts, 0) + COALESCE(reshares, 0)) * shares_multiplier;
    
END;

$function$
```

I tried adding:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY earned_media_direct(
            SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered), 
            CAST(SUM(message_stat.clicks) AS bigint), 
            team.earned_media_multi_clicks, 
            SUM(message_stat.likes), 
            team.earned_media_multi_likes, 
            SUM(message_stat.comments), 
            team.earned_media_multi_comments, 
            SUM(message_stat.shares), 
            team.earned_media_multi_shares) DESC
        ) AS rank
```

I am not sure I am using it right regarding my example. Is there another way to perform `ORDER BY rank`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We probably can use "subquery" approach for this

- First: we wrap your main query into subquery and omit the order inside
  it.
- Second: we do order on outer query.

```
-- outer query
SELECT * FROM (
    -- sub query (your main query)
    SELECT
        message.id,
        note,
        earned_media_direct(
            SUM(message_stat.posts_delivered)::int,
            CAST(SUM(message_stat.clicks) AS bigint),
            team.earned_media_multi_clicks::int,
            SUM(message_stat.likes)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_likes::int,
            SUM(message_stat.comments)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_comments::int,
            SUM(message_stat.shares)::int,
            team.earned_media_multi_shares::int
        ) AS media_points,
        count(*) OVER() AS total_count
    FROM message
    LEFT JOIN team ON team.id = 10
    WHERE team_id = 10
    GROUP BY message.id, team.id
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 1
) A
-- move the order to outer query
ORDER BY A.media_points;
```

Hope this help answer your question.

Reference:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure if this will be suitable solution for me, as I would like to use orderBy dynamically based on the parameters I pass.. One of them is "rank".. Is is possible to ORDER BY media_points inside main query? @WilliamLuisan